# Passar parâmetros no método GET do retrofit2 para Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Fala pessoal, beleza?

Tô tentando passa um parâmetro no retrofit, mas não tô conseguindo. Confesso que sou bem iniciante em Android. Dei uma pesquisada, mas o que eu tentei não deu certo até agora.

Como eu testei o método da minha api no postman:
http://localhost:8080/api/user/?userEmail=teste@email.com

Até aqui, tudo tranquilo.

Interface UserService

```java
public interface UserService {

    @GET("user/?userEmail")
    Call<User> getUserByEmail(@Query(value = "email", encoded = true) String email);
```

Chamada na Main Activity

```java
public void getUserByEmail(String email) {

       Call<User> call = userService.getUserByEmail(email);

       call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
               if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                   User userResponse = response.body();
                   Long id = userResponse.getUserId();
                   String emailU = userResponse.getEmail();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

           }
       });


   }
```

E bom, é isso. Inicialmente eu estava usando @Path na interface e passando a string igual da url que foi no postman.

Comment: O serviço está esperando `userEmail` ou `email`?

Comment: Cara, acabei de ver aqui suas respostas. Na minha api, o parâmetro é userEmail. Creio que já entendi. Vou testar aqui e daí dou um retorno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve indicar o nome do parâmetro apenas na anotação `@Query`, no seu caso a montagem da URL vai ficar incorreta: `user/?userEmail&email=xpto`

Alterando o path do seguinte modo deve surtir efeito

```
@GET("/user")
Call<User> getUserByEmail(@Query(value = "email", encoded = true) String email);
```

Verifique se em sua anotação deve ser `@Query(value = "email", encoded = true)` ou `@Query(value = "userEmail", encoded = true)`.

Você também pode utilizar `@Path` se preferir:

```
@GET("/user?userEmail={userEmail}")
Call<User> getUserByEmail(@Path("userEmail") String email);
```

Caso você tenha muitos parâmetros, você pode utilizar `@QueryMap`, que flexibiliza a passagem de vários parâmetros sem precisar de um template:

```
@GET("/user")
Call<User> getUserByEmail(@QueryMap Map<String, String> params);
```

Comment: Cara, deu certo aqui. Obrigado pela ajuda, vou marcar como a melhor resposta.